# Rails Action rendering html instead of json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am using Rails 3. I really have a strange problem. I have a list of Country States as a select box, and I have hooked up `jquery's` `$.ajax({})`, on change of the States select box.

The action takes a state code as a parameter and returns the districts that belong to a specific state. When the request is sent to `/districts?state=1`, it responds with a status code of `302(found)` and then it also sends the current html page as a response.

Following is my code:

```
# Controller Action

def districts
  state = params[:state]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json{ render :json => get_districts(state) }
  end
end


# jQUery Request:

$.ajax({
    url: '<%= districts_path %>',
    data: {state: 1},
    success: function(data){
        for(i in data){
            options += '<option value="'+data[i].code+'">'+data[i].district+'</option>'
        }

        $("#some_element").html('<select id="some_district" name="some_district">'+options+'</select>')
    }
});
```

Comment: could you do `'<%= districts_path, format: "json" %>'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 302, in my experience, is due to authentication issues.  You should consider posting your controller code/routes and any authentication as well as any errors that may be occurring.

Comment: You were correct. It was an authorization issue problem.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `dataType` option to the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= districts_path %>',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {state: 1},
```

#### edit added comma